# Qlikview Rolling 52Wk Report

Tags: qlikview

I have a strange issue with Qlikview with a rolling 52 Week report that show sales units for items which works back from the current week (39) to week 40 of previous year. What is happening is that if an item has 0 sales for the week it populates the current week data with data with sales from a previous week. Example:

Week 39 (Current Week) had 0 sales of an item.

On my Qlikview table it kept the week 39 label but populated the sales data from the previous week (38) as there was sales. I have checked all of the table properties and unchecked suppress zero values, show all values etc.

How do i stop the table from hiding 0 values if there is no sales for the current week?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the expression you are using? Do you have any accumulation enabled?

Comment: Hi @BrunoMarques I have created a variable that uses this expression: Sum({<WeekSEQ={"$(=Max(WeekSEQ)-$1)"}>}QTY) then in the expression box i use $(v52WkU(0)) to get the units. to get the previous week i use $(v52WkU(1)) and so on.

Comment: And if you check the value of $(v52WkU(1)), $(v52WkU(0)) they are correctly calculated?

Comment: Yes they calculate correctly, Its just when you drill down to a specific item it will only start the 52 week from the first week of sales. I need it to show it from current week back 52 weeks which is not what it is currently doing.

Comment: I'm guessing that the data is not showing because you don't have records from that specific item on certain dates. One way to overcome this could be to force Qlik to generate dummy data for all combinations of items x weeks with a sales value of zero. Just an idea, without more information this would be my best guess.